# Inserting text in a Word Doc does not work (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have a document a.docx with a bookmark "bmTest".
This is a part of my .net-Code:

```
oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("a.docx")
oDoc.Bookmarks("bmTest").Range.InsertAfter("XXX")
...
```

Word is started, a.docx is loaded, but no text is inserted at that bookmark.
When I rename the bookmark in my code or in the Word document VB throws an error that it does not exist. So the names seem to be right.

What am I doing wrong? How can I insert text remotely in a Word document?

Comment: Can you add more code ? Otherwise i doubt anyone might be able to help you.

Comment: Your code works for me, although I added `oWord.Visible = True` so I could see the results (the modified document isn't saved by this code).

Comment: Ok, I minimized the code. oword.visible=true is implemented, too.

Comment: And @noidea: that is all the relevant and not working code...

Comment: Yes, but what's around it can possibly affect the result, especially since the code itself is not giving an error. We don't know, for example, if you're closing the document, saving the document, or whatever.

Comment: Yes I am shure... and opening the file is neither my problem nor my question

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is solved. The code shown above is working. There seems to be a problem with the opened docx document (a customer form) - it may be corrupt.
After using another form the code works :/